# How to scrape table in specific subsection of a page?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape a specific table from a page containing multiple tables. The url I'm using includes the subsection where the table is located.

So far I tried scraping all tables and select the one I need manually

```
wikiurl = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2011_in_Strikeforce#Strikeforce_Challengers:_Britt_vs._Sayers'
response=requests.get(wikiurl)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
table_class = "toccolours"
table = soup.find_all('table', table_class) # find all tables
# and pick right one 
df=pd.read_html(str(table[15]))
```

Is it possible to use the information in the url `#Strikeforce_Challengers:_Britt_vs._Sayers` to only scrape the table in this section?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the way - Simply `split()` url once by `#`, last element from result by `_` and `join()` the elements to use them in the [`css selector`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) with `:-soup-contains()`:

```
table = soup.select_one(f'h2:-soup-contains("{" ".join(url.split("#")[-1].split("_"))}") ~ .toccolours')
```

##### Example

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2011_in_Strikeforce#Strikeforce_Challengers:_Britt_vs._Sayers'
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content)

table = soup.select_one(f'h2:-soup-contains("{" ".join(url.split("#")[-1].split("_"))}") ~ .toccolours')

pd.read_html(str(table))[0]
```